# Cant test IFormFile uploads using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore in net 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have the following request structure :

```
 public class UploadFilesRequest
 {
    public int[] UploadOptions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UploadInfo> Files { get; set; }
 }

public class UploadInfo
 {
    public int UploadOption { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Content { get; set; }
 }
```

And my upload method looks like this :

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Test([FromForm] UploadFilesRequest uploadFilesRequest)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

But I'm not able to test this method using swagger, because the Swagger UI, it's not able to
detect that my request contains files. Any ideas how to fix this ? my version of Swashbuckle.ASP.NET.Core is the latest : 6.3.0

Answer (score 1):

`Swagger` does not support the transmission of this format by default, So I suggest you use postman to send requset.

You can write test like:

[image]

[image]

I have tested and it works fine.